# How do I access the current annotation's NSString when in "prepareForSegue"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, segue

Pin .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import MapKit;

@interface Pin : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

NSString *time;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *time;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end

Pin.m

#import "Pin.h"

@implementation Pin

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize time;
@end
```

How I set my Pin in the view

```
Pin *newPin = [[Pin alloc]init];
            newPin.coordinate = userCoordinate;

    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-DD-yyy hh:mm a"];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
    newPin.time = resultString;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newPin];
```

What Happens when I press the callout

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender:view];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
      if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Details"])
     {
        InfoViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
     }
}
```

Now in the second view controller that is accessed with the identifier "Details", I have a NSString that will hold the time of the specific pin.
How can I pass the current pin's time NSString to the next view's NSString?

Note: There will but multiple pins set at different times on the map and I have tried [Passing data from annotations to detail view iOS using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986571/passing-data-from-annotations-to-detail-view-ios-using-storyboard) and tried to use

```
Pin *an = (Pin *)mapView.annotation;
```

but it only lets me used an array for the mapView annotation

```
Pin *an = (Pin *)mapView.annotations;
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your annotation via the `annotation` property of the annotation view and then pass this as the sender to `performSegueWithIdentifier` like so

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender:view.annotation];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
      if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Details"])
     {
        Pin *myPin=(Pin *)sender;
        InfoViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.time=myPin.time;
     }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "vc.time = myPin.time" in the last line of your code. The program crashes and I get  "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKPinAnnotationView time]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d25420'"

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed that.  Did you change the sender to view.annotation ?