# MKAnnotation - How to display a button on the annotation bubble

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am trying to use a map to set annotation in it, where the user wants to put it.

I want the user to touch the screen where he wants to put a pin, and by clicking on the appeared pin, he can be redirected to another view where he can put details.

I followed several tutorials to make the button appear on the right of the callout, but this does not work...

Here is my code :

MAPpin is the NSObject file :

MAPpin.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MAPpin : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@end
```

MAPpin.m :

```
#import "MAPpin.h"

@implementation MAPpin

@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle, mapView;


@end
```

And my view controller :

MAPwelcomeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MAPKit/MKAnnotation.h>
#import "MAPAppDelegate.h"
#import "MAPpin.h"

@interface MAPwelcomeViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
- (IBAction)longpress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

and the MAPwelcomeViewController.m :

```
#import "MAPwelcomeViewController.h"
#import "MAPpin.h"
#import "myAnnotation.h"
#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

@interface MAPwelcomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation MAPwelcomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    }
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //1
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 40.740848;
    zoomLocation.longitude= -73.991145;
    // 2
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.3*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.3*METERS_PER_MILE);
    [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];


}
/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/






#pragma mark -MapView Delegate Methods
//6
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    //7
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    //8
    static NSString *identifier = @"myAnnotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView * annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!annotationView)
    {
        //9
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    return annotationView;
}

- (IBAction)longpress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D loccoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];


    myAnnotation *ann = [[myAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:loccoord title:@"Test"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];

}

@end
```

So following (http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/mapkit-tutorial-for-ios-beginners/"this links") I added the following method :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

But when I run the app, no button is showing... what do you think I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance,

regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the map view's `delegate` is not set so the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method never gets called and the map view creates a default red pin with no callout accessory button.

In the storyboard, right-click on the map view control and connect its `delegate` outlet to the View Controller.

Or, in code, in the `viewDidLoad` method, before setting `showsUserLocation`, set the `delegate` programmatically:

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

---

Some unrelated comments...

Once the button is appearing, to handle the user tapping the callout accessory, a recommended approach is to implement the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method.  See the answer to [MKAnnotationView Push to View Controller when DetailDesclosure Button is Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked) for an example.

A separate issue I should point out is that the gesture handler method isn't checking the gesture recognizer's `state` before creating an annotation.  So what can happen is multiple pins can get created while the user is still doing a single long press.  To avoid this, add a check like this at the top of the `longpress:` method:

```
if (sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    return;
}
```

Another unrelated thing is that the code is creating an annotation of type `myAnnotation` by doing `myAnnotation alloc` but the annotation class you've shown is of type `MAPpin`.

Finally, adding an `MKMapView` as an IBOutlet and property in the `MAPpin` class is **completely** unnecessary.  You should remove it from there before it leads to confusion.

Comment: Hey Anna, Thanks very much this worked !Thanks a lot for your other comments ! regards