# Segue from a MapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, segue

I’m new to iphone development.  What I’m trying to do is have a view controller with a mapview and annotation callouts that when one of the callouts is selected it will segue into another detail view controller with information, etc pertaining to the particular callout that was touched.  In interface builder when I try to ctrl drag from the mapview to the detail view controller nothing happens..I can’t create a segue.  I can’t select any of the annotation callouts because they are all in written in my .h & .m files.  What am I doing wrong?  I know I have to have an identifier for the segue in order to proceed, but I can’t create the segue.

Comment: Segue link 2 UIViewController. Call it by code if you wait for a particular trigger with your MapView

Comment: That's what I believe I'm attempting to do.  Ctrl drag from view controller with map view to another (new) view controller.

Comment: This would seem to me to be a very common question, but I can't find anything nor can I get any answers.  The only way to perform a segue is to have an identifier for the segue which can only be done vie interface builder.  But I can't get a segue from my MKMApView to my new view controller. ???

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked

Comment: Bump. id like to know the answer to this question also!

How do you control drag to create the segue in the first place??