# How do you pass id from a view controller with a map view to another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

i am using parse to retrieve data, how do i pass an object ID from a viwecontroller which has a map view to another view controller ,

```
 -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MapToDeal" sender:view.annotation];
    NSLog(@"%@",view.annotation.title);
}
```

Comment: You can use delegate and protocol.

Comment: could you help with a sample code

Comment: You can ref this web site http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-an-objective-c-delegate/

Comment: how do you pass the data to the second view controller, when a annotation is tapped

Comment: I use delegate and protocol.......

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this method in .m file

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"MapToDeal"])
  {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    detailViewController.annotview = sender; //here annoteview is  object in DetailViewcontroller
  }
}
```

or 
you can also do like this

```
In mapView Delegate method

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MapToDeal" sender:view];
}

In prepareForSegue:

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MapToDeal"])
    {
        MapPoint *annotation = (MapPoint *)view.annotation;

        DetailViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        dvc.name = annotation.name;
        dvc.anyproperty = annotation.anyproperty;

    }
}
```