# How do I make my annotation callout lead to a new View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, callout

As of now, I have a DetailViewController in my storyboard with no segues to/from. Here is my code in the map view controller...

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;
MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"User"];


UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
MyPin.draggable = NO;
MyPin.highlighted = YES;
MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;
UIImageView *myCustomImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CorgiRunner2 Final.png"]];
myCustomImage.image = profPic;
myCustomImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,31,31);
MyPin.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myCustomImage;

[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pinTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return MyPin;
}




-(void)pinTouched:(UIButton *)sender
{
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

detailViewController.profName1 = profName;
detailViewController.profPic1 = profPic;
}
```

How do I make it so that when the call out is pressed, my Detail View Controller shows up?

Comment: Just a note: All your questions so far have already been asked and answered several times by other users on SO.  Please search thoroughly on SO, the documentation, and elsewhere before posting potentially duplicate questions (and re-posting your own questions again is not a good approach either -- edit your existing question instead and explain why the posted answer didn't work for you).

Comment: For your current question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked for an example.

Comment: By the way, don't use addTarget if you're going to use the built-in delegate method calloutAccessoryControlTapped.  The map view will call its delegate method automatically if you set the accessory view and its delegate is set.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"tapped");
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.profName1 = profName;
    detailViewController.profPic1 = profPic;
}
```

Don't forget to set your `mapView` delegates and make sure this delegate method gets called.

Hope this helps

Comment: how do officially set the mapView delegates?

Comment: also, the method you provided still doesn't make the view change.

Comment: if you dont set the delegate this method will not get called.

Comment: @Ty_, I think the OP's point is that this code doesn't actually show `detailViewController` because all the code shown does is create the VC but doesn't actually show it using a segue (the OP is using storyboard).

Comment: In the question, it says he is using storyboard and the current question's code doesn't show the VC either.  It just creates it.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE
I instead connected my mapView to my DetailView Controller in the main storyboard, and used

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender:view];
}
```

THIS WORKS FOR ME