# How to get parent tag of UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have simple app with Map and pins attached to it. After clicking on pin on map, `pinView` is created, on wchich I have button with action called let's say `ButtonPressed`.
I want to know from which pin it was pressed. I tried something like :

```
      (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

UIButton *but = (UIButton*) sender;

NSLog(@"SEG PLZ SEG CMON %tu",but.superview.tag);
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segu" sender:sender];

}
```

But it always returns 0, no matter that I set tag for 5.
Okay I post code for adding buttons as you wanted :

```
 - (MKPinAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)myannotation{

    MKPinAnnotationView *view = nil;
    //MKPinAnnotationView *view=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"HotSpotsLoc"];

    if(myannotation !=mapView.userLocation){
        view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
        [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        if(nil == view) {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                     initWithAnnotation:myannotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        }

                    UIButton *btnViewVenue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        [view.rightCalloutAccessoryView setTag:50];
        [btnViewVenue addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView=btnViewVenue;
        view.enabled = YES;
        view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        view.canShowCallout = YES;
        view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
        //view.animatesDrop = YES;

        UIButton *btnViewwVenue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd ] ;

        [btnViewwVenue addTarget:self action:@selector(addImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [view setTag:50];

        view.leftCalloutAccessoryView=btnViewwVenue;
        view.enabled = YES;
        view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        view.canShowCallout = YES;
        view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you add the buttons in the view please

Comment: When using the rightCalloutAccessoryView and leftCalloutAccessoryView, you don't need to do `addTarget` nor do you need to use tags (please don't) nor do you need to look at superviews (please don't).  Instead, implement the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method and the annotation object is available via view.annotation.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `leftCalloutAccessoryView` and `rightCalloutAccessoryView` does not necessarily add the views as subviews of `view`. If you need this relationship to be explicit, consider subclassing `UIButton`.

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
@property (weak) MKPinAnnotationView *annotation;
@end

@implementation MyButton
@end


// Then...

(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

  MyButton *but = (MyButton*) sender;

  NSLog(@"SEG PLZ SEG CMON %tu",but.annotation.tag);
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segu" sender:sender];

}
```