# Who Call prepareForSegue?

Tags: swift, view

Hy guys i have a problem
in my app i have a map with any annotations as MKPointAnnotation

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView: MKAnnotationView!,
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped value: UIControl!)
{
        if value == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView
        {  
            return performSegueWithIdentifier("newSegue", sender: annotationView) 
        }  
}
```

and then the other code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "newSegue" {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as newViewController}}
```

i can i find what MKpointAnnotation call the performSegueWithIdentifier and prepareForSegue too?
then i know what kind of objects put in my view :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked.  It's in Objective-C but the logic is the same.  The annotation object in prepareForSegue would be basically sender.annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined properties in your destinationViewController that match the properties in your MKAnnotionView you could do this in prepareForSegue:

```
if let senderObject = sender as? MKAnnotationView {
   destinatinViewController.coordinate = senderObject.coordinate
   destinatinViewController.title = senderObject.title
   destinatinViewController.subtitle = senderObject.subtitle
}
```

Comment: The sender will indeed be an MKAnnotationView so the annotation will be senderObject.annotation.  The view and the annotation are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I solve that way:

1) Link the MapKitViewControler do the `SecondViewControler` with the Ctrl key and named the segue as "MapInfo". 
2) On MapKitViewControler creat a variable `varToPass`
3) On SecondViewControler creat a variable `varToReceive`
4) Use a Dictionary on MapKitViewControler to store your data (can be String our your custom class, like `MyAnnotation`  above, with data points and other informations): `var myDicyionary = [String : MyAnnotation]()`

```
import MapKit
import AddressBook

class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation
{
    let identifier : String
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(identifier: String, title: String, subtitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
    {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate

        super.init()
    }
}
```

5) Add the points on MapView on Load for example and use the identifier field (type String in this case) to identify which pin is clicked:

```
let annotation = MyAnnotation(identifier: userId, title: userName, subtitle: subtitle, coordinate: location)
self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

6) Identify which pin is clicked and save it on a class variable and force the prepare for segue call:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!)
{
    let anotation = view.annotation as! MyAnnotation        

    if (control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView)
    {
        println("Button Right pressed!")

        self.varToPass = self.myDicyionary[anotation.identifier]

        //Force prepare for segue call
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UserInfo", sender: self)
    }
    else if (control == view.leftCalloutAccessoryView)
    {
        println("Button Left pressed!")
    }
}
```

7) Pass the variable for the segue that you want

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "MapInfo")
        {
            let mapInfoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MapKitViewControler

            mapInfoViewController.varToReceive = self.varToPass
        }
    }
```

8) The variabels `varToPass`and `varToReceive` can be String or a custom class like MyAnnotation.