# Pass data between view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

I'm trying to pass an object (PFObject) from an view controller to another,

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    RestauCardViewController *restauCard = [[RestauCardViewController alloc]init];
    RestaurantAnnotation *restoAnnotation = (RestaurantAnnotation *)view.annotation;

    restauCard.restaurant = restoAnnotation.restaurant;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToCard" sender:nil];
}
```

When I try to display the object in the other view controller I got null:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface RestauCardViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic) PFObject *restaurant;

@end
```

This is my viewDidLoad function

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"The restaurant name is : %@",_restaurant[@"nom"]);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked.  Instead of using a property or ivar to store the selection, pass the annotation `view` as `sender`.  It makes the code more self-contained and uses functionality already provided by the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use -prepareForSegue to manage this situation, and you'll need an iVar to keep the restaurant name.

So in the top of your map's .m file, add an ivar `NSString`

```
@implementation yourViewController{

    NSString *sRestName;   //This is empty until the user selects a restaurant

}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    sRestName = //Set the name of your restaurent here, it's just a string. 
                //You could set any other type of object (a restaurent object or a PFOjbect or anything, 
               //just change the ivar accordingly
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToCard" sender:nil];
}
```

What you're going to do is replace your old code with the code just above, you just need to perform the segue to call the following method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"fromHomeToList"]){
        RestauCardViewController *vc = (RestauCardViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.restaurant = sRestName; //here you're just giving the property of the new controller the content of your ivar. 
}
```

That way you can pass an object from your map tap to your next controller. You're also sure it will never be nil because the user tapped it ; if it was nil, well, he couldn't have tapped it in the first place !

Note that I assumed you were using a string for your restaurant name, but if you change the ivar on the top, you can use anything you want, **as long as you can retrieve it from tapping on the map**. If you can't, I need more details to walk you through another solution.

Ask me if you have any quesiton, otherwise this should work !

Comment: Thank you verry much thats work :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the restaurent inside the UIViewController method "`prepareSegue...`".  It's called after you `performeSegueWithIdentifier`, so the destination controller is accessible and you can test the segue.identifier and set the restaurent to the controller.

Example :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueRestaurentDetails"]) {

        RestauCardViewController *destController = (RestaurentDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        destController.restaurant = (RestaurantAnnotation *)view.annotation;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how i can access to the view from the prepareForSegue method ?

Comment: You can store it before calling "performeSegueWithIdentifier" inside a private variable like `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *viewToDisplay;`   . Then you get it like `(RestaurantAnnotation *)_viewToDisplay.annotation;`

Comment: Don't use a property for this, it's accessible from the outside of the class which you don't need. Use an ivar instead ; see my answer for more details. Both our answers are fairly close to each other

Comment: Private properties declared in `@interaface` in **.m** are not accessible from outside.

ivar are no more needed... update to the last objective-c practices please.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` method in ViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToCard"]) {
        RestauCardViewController *controller = (RestauCardViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.restaurant = (RestaurantAnnotation *)view.annotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i get this error :  controller.restaurant = (RestaurantAnnotation *)view.annotation;
Use of undeclared identifier view

Comment: how you declare `view` in your code?

Comment: here :  -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToCard" sender:nil];
}

Comment: Boyi Li your code is wrong, you haven't declared view in your prepareforsegue method, this won't compile.

Comment: How I can do to declare the view in my prepareforsefue method ?

Comment: Is that possible that you get the MKAnnotation directly? Or you could create a local temporary variable

Comment: Thank you verry much you saved my day :-)